# Trying to add a new row to a "Shared Data Extension" using SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ssjs

I'm trying to add a new row to a Shared Data Extension using SSJS.
When I try to run my code I got this error:

`"There was an error Adding the row(s)."`

**In another environment of Marketing cloud, the code works and does not give errors.
Why is there an error?**

My code:

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core", "1");

    try {
        var de = DataExtension.Init("EXTERNAL KEY");
        var data = {
            status: "status",
            errorMsg: "errorMsg"
        }
       Write(de.Rows.Add(data));
    }catch(error) {
        Write(Stringify(error));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you running this in the parent BU?

"Shared" means "parent" context, always, no matter from where it's shared.
If you run this from child BU context, it might not find the DE?

Comment: Thanks, I tried to run it from a child BU...From there I got the error.

Comment: @DanielRomano Since you are running into the child BU but in Share data extensions. Did you use "ENT." as prefix? Also instead of External Name Try using Data extension name -  Like this - DataExtension.Init("ENT.Data Extension Name");Let me know if this works!

Comment: @razor It works thank you so much!!!!!!!

Comment: Now I tried to read the DE. I used it like this: Rows.Retrieve() and I got 0 Result

Comment: @DanielRomano Since this resolves the answer to your original question. please mark is as a right one. So that it will be helpful for others. Please raise this new one as a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are running into the child BU but in Share data extensions.

Please you use "ENT." as prefix. 
Also instead of External Name Try using Data external Key.

Like this - DataExtension.Init("ENT.Data External Key");

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the WHY. Shared data extensions are owned by the enterprise regardless of what BU made them.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/183451)